# Vim integration with GHCi

Tags: vim, integration, ghci

I'm trying to use Vim as a Haskell IDE, and, though I'm not a hardcore Vim user, I enjoy the mode-based way of editing.

The only thing I'm missing after my Emacs period is integration with GHCi. In the latter editor you can just type `C-c C-l` (the same shortcut for all kinds of REPL environments) to reload the current source file and switch to the split window with the interpreter in it. That possibility is indispensable for rapid prototyping, TDD and so on. I'm sure that I've done considerable work in attempts to get the same feature in Vim, but with no significant result.

If anyone has already dealt with such a task, please provide a link or a hint to the solution.

Comment: You might as well write your solution as a proper answer to this question, and then mark it as answered.

Comment: Ah, I see, I'll do that, thanks! I'm new here, so I don't know common procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a script that does exactly what I want, it's called [SHIM](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2356). Good luck, guys!